# Why does Hide all input fail to return back to full code cell in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook

This problem can be repeated, and I just find another similar code that have the same problem.

**Usage**: copy following code, and insert before the first cell, then paste it into and run that cell, finally a button will show below, clicking it will toggle the new cell to show or hide, ***but*** with a problem that the line number cannot appear automatically when I want to show it from hidden state, unless I click the editing area, which fires some event to make it back to normal.

How to fix it and the same problem of Hide All Input extension?

```
    from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
    toggle_code_str = '''
    <form action="javascript:code_toggle()"><input type="submit" id="toggleButton" value="Toggle Code"></form>
    '''

    toggle_code_prepare_str = '''
        <script>
        function code_toggle() {
            if ($('div.cell.code_cell.rendered.selected div.input').css('display')!='none'){
                $('div.cell.code_cell.rendered.selected div.input').hide();
            } else {
                $('div.cell.code_cell.rendered.selected div.input').show();
            }
        }
        </script>

    '''

    display(HTML(toggle_code_prepare_str + toggle_code_str))

    def toggle_code():
        display(HTML(toggle_code_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Found solution

Add to _hide_input\main.js_ this line:
`cell.element.trigger("click");`
after
`cell.metadata.hide_input = ! cell.metadata.hide_input;`
and save the js file and reopen that page, then shift into rise mode, everything renders pretty when toggle hide or not!